# I am confused with the disconnect between AUC score and GridSearchcv'S best_score_?

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have been using GridSearchCV to tune the hyperparameters of three different models. Through hyperparameter tuning I have gotten AUC's of 0.65 (Model A), 0.74 (Model B), and 0.77 (Model C).

However when I return the "best_score_" for each grid search I am getting the scores of 0.72 (Model A), 0.68 (Model B), and 0.71 (Model C).

I am confused about why these scores are noticeably different, for example Model A has the weakest AUC but the strongest "best_score". Is this ok? Does this mean that more tuning likely needs to be done?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you obtaining the first set of AUCs?  What metric are you using for the grid search (i.e., what is `best_score_`?)  What kinds of models are A, B, C?

Comment: Agree with @Ben Reiniger - it would be beneficial to define what best_score is. My guess is that it's the best score seen for that model over all iterations used -- for that model, and AUC reported is probably an average.  If you knew what best-score was, you would probably know the answer.

Comment: I am obtaining the AUCs through a RandomForestClassifier. The models contain biomarkers to predict a disease. The best_score_ is the average of all cv folds (mean cross validation score). @BenReiniger

Comment: But are the AUCs from a separate test set, or...?  Did you use the default `scoring`, or `"roc_auc"`?

Comment: I used the default scoring...should I have used "roc_auc"? AUCs are from a seperate test set. @BenReiniger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main issues here, in my mind.

1. You're comparing accuracy and AUROC. The default `scoring` in `GridSearchCV` uses the model object's `score` method, which is accuracy for classification models like `RandomForestClassifier`.  There's no guarantee that two metrics agree on the best model, and [accuracy isn't a great metric](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/232706).  [One specific possibility here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/90686/232706) is that model A does a poor job at rank-ordering compared to the others, but the others perform poorly at the default classification cutoff of 0.5 used for the accuracy metrics.
2. You're comparing test set performance with hyperparameter-selection scores. The `best_score_` is optimistically biased because of the selection process. If one of the selections resulted in a more-overfit model, it might have worse test score drop than others.